# useradd not in amazonlinux base image

Tags: docker, amazon-linux-2

It seems that `useradd` is not in amazonlinux docker base image.

`useradd` will work when when my Dockerfile install openldap-devel, so `RUN useradd my_user` will work when I my image have the following:

```
FROM amazonlinux

RUN yum -y install python3 \
    gcc \
    python3-pip \
    python3-devel \
    openldap-devel
```

When my image is just build from

```
FROM amazonlinux

RUN yum -y install python3 \
    gcc \
    python3-pip \
    python3-devel
```

The command  `RUN useradd my_user` fails with the error message `/bin/sh: useradd: command not found`

How do I install `useradd` in an amazonlinux  base image without having to install all openldap-devel

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I managed to figure out what package `useradd` belongs by running the following command on an AmazonLinux EC2 machine:

```
$ yum whatprovides /usr/sbin/useradd

2:shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-24.amzn2.x86_64 : Utilities for managing accounts and shadow password files
Repo        : amzn2-core
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/useradd
```

So changing my Dockerfile to the following made it work:

```
FROM amazonlinux

RUN yum -y install python3 \
    python3-pip \
    shadow-utils
```

Comment: is it dependent on python itself?

Comment: to answer my own question - no python is not required for shadow-utils functions

Comment: you may still needed to refer to it with absolute path: /usr/sbin/useradd

Answer (score 7):

you can use the `shadow-utils` package as demeter has pointed out.

In my case, installing `shadow-utils` took too long in order to create my docker image, because it installed many dependencies. So I'll give you 2 alternatives:

##### 1 - Use docker USER command:

You can do this in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11.0.14-al2
USER 1000
```

This will allow you to start the container with a non-root user. From [here](https://github.com/amazonlinux/container-images/issues/28), you can see that you don't need the user to exist. The downside is that this user has no name and no $HOME. I think this would usually be ok, but if there's any software in the container that needs a $HOME folder, it could give some problems.

##### 2 - Use an existing user:

In the container, if you run `cat /etc/passwd` you'll see a list of existing users. Usually you'll have the `nobody` user that has the least permissions. So in your Dockerfile you can do:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11.0.14-al2
USER nobody
```

and you're good

Comment: I liked the idea of using `nobody`, but ran into the problem that (on Amazon Linux 2) the `nobody` user has a `$HOME` of `/`.  That caused issues because I had references like `$HOME/blah` then ended up resolving to paths like `//blah`.

Answer (score 1):

Running docker on amazonlinux2, these days I use this:

RUN yum install -y /usr/sbin/adduser

Docker it seems does the equivalent of whatprovides and loads the right things, in this case, shadow-utils and libsemanage.